# Possible php time outs causing 500 server error?

Tags: php, joomla-3.5

I was hoping for some advice regarding what I think is a time out error? My problem is that on the first few loads my pages can fail to load and show a 500 error, but if I continue to refresh, or navigate away and then back again they load and I can carry on working. It is however, proving very difficult to find the issue as it is intermittent.

I am at present upgrading my template files and extensions to the latest version with the hope of moving to PHP 7, but in the meantime is there anyway that I can prevent/catch/rectify this time out issue?

My php.ini file contains:

```
max_execution_time = 5000
max_input_time = 5000
memory_limit = 512M
display_errors = Off
log_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

But there aren't any real errors being logged.

Comment: Donna, please progress this page toward a system-recognized resolution if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Erratic issues are the hardest to debug, but I suggest you do the following:

- Enable the MySQL slow query log (in your my.cnf file) and check if there are heavy queries taking place on your website
- Disable modules on your website (starting with slideshow modules) and continuously check to see when the problem goes away, when it does, then it means that you have found the offending module.
- If it's not any module, then disable non-core plugins one by one until the problem is no more.
- If it's not a plugin, then it might be that your website is hacked. Try overwriting the core files with those from a fresh Joomla install and see if that helps.

Comment: thank you. I will do just that. I'm just finishing my template upgrades and will start looking into this. I have noticed some duplicate queries being logged in the debug console, so these need to be looked at also. Regards Donna

Answer (score 0):

500 errors can sometimes be caused by an incorrect configuration in the .htaccess file or by a resource limitation in the hosting plan.

Given the intermittent nature of the problem you describe, it sounds like it might be a resource limitation issue.

Enabling GZip and the Joomla cache in System Configuration and enabling the page cache in plugin manager may help if these aren't enabled already.